The mentioned error occurred when I tried to flash a Nordic DK using VS Code
The error occurred when I tried to flash a Nordic Development Kit (DK) using VS Code. The application built successfully, but the issue arose during the flashing process of the DK.
- west flash: using runner nrfjprog
-- runners.nrfjprog: Flashing file: /home/nadim/ble/bt-fund/lesson1/blefund_less1_exer1/build/zephyr/zephyr.hex
[error] [SeggerBackend] - Error in dlopen: libjlinkarm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[error] [ Worker] - Dll failed to open.
[error] [ Client] - Encountered error -101: Command open executed for 25 milliseconds with result -101
ERROR: JLinkARM DLL load failed. Try again. If it keeps failing, please
ERROR: reinstall latest JLinkARM from Segger webpage.
NOTE: For additional output, try running again with logging enabled (--log).
NOTE: Any generated log error messages will be displayed.
FATAL ERROR: command exited with status 32: nrfjprog --program /home/nadim/ble/bt-fund/lesson1/blefund_less1_exer1/build/zephyr/zephyr.hex --sectoranduicrerase --verify -f NRF52 --snr 683419441


It's complaining about being unable to find a shared library, libjlinkarm.so. Either check the docs that came with it (is there an INSTALL file?) or check the packaging system with dpkg  -S libjlinkarm.so to find which package to install.

The answer is the question is the following:
Download the JLink_Linux_.deb package from the
https://www.segger.com/downloads/flasher/#software-for-legacy-flasher
website. Sometimes, the first command doesn't work; in that case, execute the second command directly.
sudo apt remove jlink
sudo dpkg -i JLink_Linux_<version>.deb

